# Extract delta, theta, alpha, beta and gamma waves from signals

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, fft

I want to get delta, theta, alpha, beta and gamma waves from a set of signals. And this is how, till now I am doing it:-

```
fs = 256
data=copy.deepcopy(features[:100])
data=np.reshape(data,(len(data),256,64))

# Get real amplitudes of FFT (only in postive frequencies)
fft_vals=[] 
for d in data:
    fft_vals.append(np.absolute(np.fft.fft2(d)))
fft_vals = np.array(fft_vals) 
print(fft_vals.shape)

# Get frequencies for amplitudes in Hz
fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), 1.0/fs)    
print(fft_freq.shape)      #(100)


# Define EEG bands
eeg_bands = {'Delta': (0, 4),
             'Theta': (4, 8),
             'Alpha': (8, 12),
             'Beta': (12, 30),
             'Gamma': (30, 45)}

delta=[]
theta=[]
alpha=[]
beta=[]
gamma=[]

delta_labels=[]
theta_labels=[]
alpha_labels=[]
beta_labels=[]
gamma_labels=[]

delta_real=[]
theta_real=[]
alpha_real=[]
beta_real=[]
gamma_real=[]

# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:
    freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) & 
                       (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
    print(freq_ix.shape)   #prints first value of shape of each wave
    if band=='Delta':
        delta_real=data[freq_ix]
        delta_labels=labels[freq_ix]
        delta=fft_vals[freq_ix]
    elif band=='Theta':
        theta_real=data[freq_ix]
        theta_labels=labels[freq_ix]
        theta=fft_vals[freq_ix]
    elif band=='Alpha':
        alpha_real=data[freq_ix]
        alpha_labels=labels[freq_ix]
        alpha=fft_vals[freq_ix]
    elif band=='Beta':
        beta_real=data[freq_ix]
        beta_labels=labels[freq_ix]
        beta=fft_vals[freq_ix]
    elif band=='Gamma':
        gamma_real=data[freq_ix]
        gamma_labels=labels[freq_ix]
        gamma=fft_vals[freq_ix]
    eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])


print(delta.shape)
print(theta.shape)
print(alpha.shape)
print(beta.shape)
print(gamma.shape)
```

But I am getting this as output as the output of all waves' shape:-

```
(2,256,64)
(2,256,64)
(1,256,64)
(7,256,64)
(6,256,64)
```

SO why am I getting just 18 values where as my data has 100 values? 
I have seen butter worth for getting all 5 waves but it isn't also working as expected so I am sure I am not understanding it right, can anyone please tell me how can I get 5 waves when a dataset of signals is passed? Any help will be much appreciated.

The range of my initial data is between -19 to +30 almost. And after applying fft2 it goes from 0-30K etc. I am really confused how can I get those 5 waves from my data.

Comment: By "18 values", I assume you mean the sum of the first items of all the printed tuples?

Comment: What is the output of `print(freq_ix.shape)`?

Comment: I have edited the question. Yeah thats what I mean by 18 values. What is happening to rest of 72 values?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between how you apply the dft and how you cut out the frequency windows. Your data are 3D, you use `fft2`, the 2D fft, which per default transforms along the _last_ two axes. This means that the first axis, the one along which you try to select the frequency bands, isn't actually in the frequency domain. - It would help if you could specify what the axes of data actually are. Which one is time for example?

Comment: I have edited the question, please tell ne why the problem still persists now.

Comment: Largely, because you are still doing the exact same thing. You are transforming along the 2nd and 3rd axes and then you filter along the first which your code suggests are features anyway, so nothing to do with time or frequencies.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more and answer the question so I can know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to put it any clearer. Look, I really think it would be best for you to grasp the fundamentals first. What is a FT? What does it mean to apply it to one or more or all dimensions in a multidimensional setting? Why does it matter which axes? What is the difference between time and frequency domains? Without that you'll never be able to understand even the simplest analysis, let alone do it yourself. Just grit your teeth and grab a textbook or even the wikipedia entry and spend some time with it.

Comment: Okay I will see that. I just know basics of fft, I guess which aren't enough to do this task. Thanks fir clarifying.

Comment: How about a minimal example that we can actually run (including some example data)?